# Creating a table with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a table using PHP.

For some reason I can't display the key. Any idea why?

Here's the table.

Here's my code that I tried:

```
<table>
   <?php
       $users = array( 
                      array('first_name' => 'RS', 'last_name' => 'AD'),
                      array('first_name' => 'SQ', 'last_name' => 'FS'),
                      array('first_name' => 'SA', 'last_name' => 'Guillen'),
                      array('first_name' => 'AS', 'last_name' => 'Gs') 
       );

       $array_number = count($users)-1; 
       foreach($users as $key => $user) {
           for($i=0; $i<=$array_number; $i++){
               echo $users[$i]['first_name'].' '. $users[$i]['last_name'].'<br>';
           } 
       }
   ?>
</table>
```

Any idea?

Comment: You should use td and tr, who making tables. Not just start at table tag and end it, try searching how to make proper tables in HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User #</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Full Name in UpperCase</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $users = array(
        array('first_name' => 'Michael', 'last_name' => 'Choi'),
        array('first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Supsupin'),
        array('first_name' => 'Mark', 'last_name' => 'Guillen'),
        array('first_name' => 'KB', 'last_name' => 'Tonel')
    );


    foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" , $key + 1 , "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $user['first_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $user['last_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $user['first_name'] . " " . $user['last_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . strtoupper($user['first_name']) . " " . strtoupper($user['last_name']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "</tr>";   
    }
    ?>

</table>
```

**Brief Explanation:**

As you have shown within your image you need to define predefined headings which can be done using `<th></th>` and rest of those values you were getting from an `$users` array which can be placed within loop.

**Note:** Here you need to use single loop not nested loops as shown in example

Comment: I've given a brief explanation and if you need some more relative explanation just point it out simply. Glad it helps you

Comment: how can I add two strlen? let's say this:  echo "<td>" . strlen($user['first_name']), strlen($user['last_name']) . "</td>";

Comment: `echo "<td>" . strlen($user['first_name']).", ".strlen($user['last_name']) . "</td>";` @RodelGarcia

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<tr>` and `<td>`.

```
      <table border="1">
           <?php

        $users = array( 
           array('first_name' => 'Michael', 'last_name' => 'Choi'),
           array('first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Supsupin'),
           array('first_name' => 'Mark', 'last_name' => 'Guillen'),
           array('first_name' => 'KB', 'last_name' => 'Tonel') 
        );

         $array_number = count($users)-1; 

                for($i=0; $i<=$array_number; $i++){
                 ?>
                 <tr> <td><?php echo $users[$i]['first_name']; ?></td><td><?php echo $users[$i]['last_name']; ?></td> </tr>
         <?php       } 

        ?>

        </table>
```

Comment: Off topic, but `border` is a purely presentational thing. Use CSS for presentation.

Comment: You can check now, `foreach` removed.I think no need to use it.

Comment: how can I add two strlen? let's say this: echo "<td>" . strlen($user['first_name']), strlen($user['last_name']) . "</td>";

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you loop over the array twice, once with the `foreach` and inside that with the `for`. But you need only one loop. Choose one.

Also, make it a habit to always use `htmlspecialchars` when echoing the contents of a variable. In this case it won't matter, but sometimes, you won't know where the variable has been!

Also, see Amol's answer.

Comment: how can I add two strlen? let's say this: echo "<td>" . strlen($user['first_name']), strlen($user['last_name']) . "</td>";

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>    <?php

$users = array(     array('first_name' => 'Michael', 'last_name' => 'Choi'),    array('first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Supsupin'),  array('first_name' => 'Mark', 'last_name' => 'Guillen'),    array('first_name' => 'KB', 'last_name' => 'Tonel')  );

$i = 1;

     foreach($users as $key => $user) {
        echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $user['first_name'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $user['last_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";  $i++;
        }


?>

</table>
```

Hope that will help

Comment: how can I add two strlen? let's say this: echo "<td>" . strlen($user['first_name']), strlen($user['last_name']) . "</td>";

Answer (score 0):

`<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User #</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Full Name in UpperCase</th>
    </tr>`

`<?php
    $users = array(
        array('first_name' => 'Michael', 'last_name' => 'Choi'),
        array('first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Supsupin'),
        array('first_name' => 'Mark', 'last_name' => 'Guillen'),
        array('first_name' => 'KB', 'last_name' => 'Tonel')
    );`

```
foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" , $key + 1 , "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $user['first_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $user['last_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $user['first_name'] . " " . $user['last_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . strtoupper($user['first_name']) . " " . strtoupper($user['last_name']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
}
?>
```

`