# How to change multidimensional array into html table report php?

Tags: php, html

I have a multidimensional array like this:-

```
$data = array (
  'SalaryHeadName' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Basic',
    1 => 'PF',
  ),
  'SalaryHeadType' => 
  array (
    0 => 'CR',
    1 => 'DR',
  ),
  'Amount' => 
  array (
    0 => 6000,
    1 => 400,
  ),
)
```

how to change it into html table report like by using foreach loop or for loop thank in advance.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: what you tired so far to archive this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a table with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199218/creating-a-table-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not general, its specific to your problem.

```
$data = array('SalaryHeadName'=>array(0=>'Basic',1=>'PF'),'SalaryHeadType'=>array(0=>'CR',1=>'DR'),'Amount'=>array(0=>6000,1=>400));

     $array_keys = array_keys($data);

    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <?php foreach ($array_keys as $key) {?>
            <th><?php echo $key ?></th>
            <?php } ?>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php for ($i=0; $i<count($data['SalaryHeadName']);$i++) {?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['SalaryHeadName'][$i] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['SalaryHeadType'][$i] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['Amount'][$i] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much basically I am new in programming. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want,

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'SalaryHeadName' => array(
        0 => 'Basic',
        1 => 'PF'
    ) ,
    'SalaryHeadType' => array(
        0 => 'CR',
        1 => 'DR'
    ) ,
    'Amount' => array(
        0 => 6000,
        1 => 400
    )
);
?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <?php

foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td>";
    foreach($value as $value1)
        {
        echo "<td>$value1</td>";
        }

    echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
</table>
```